# Firebase firestore does not add anything but without an error

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I tried to connect my react native app to the firebase as following. After executing this 'add post' function neither generating an error message or storing the data in firebase. But the photo uploading function is working as charm. Also I can authenticate and create new users.  I would like to know the reason for this issue?

> Current firebase dependency "firebase": "^7.14.2". I  also inspected both "^6.6.2" and  "^7.9.0"

**Add post function**

```
        const remoteUri = await this.uploadPhotoAsync(localUri, `photos/${this.uid}/${Date.now()}`);

        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
           this. fireStore
                .collection("posts")
                .add({
                    text: text,
                    uid: this.uid,
                    timestamp: this.timeStamp,
                    image: remoteUri
                })
                .then(ref => {
                    res(ref);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    rej(error);
                });
        });
    };
```

**Photo uploading function**

```
 uploadPhotoAsync=async (uri, filename) =>{
      //  const uploadUri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? uri.replace('file://', '') : uri;

        //const path=`file://photos/${this.uid}/${Date.now()}.jpg`
       //const path='/storage/emulated/0/Download/20200123_104742.jpg'

       return new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
        const response = await fetch(uri);
        const file = await response.blob();

        let upload = firebase
            .storage()
            .ref(filename)
            .put(file);

        upload.on(
            "state_changed",
            snapshot => {},
            err => {
                rej(err);
            },
            async () => {
                const url = await upload.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
                res(url);
            }
        );
    });
```